# how to get last three words of a string?

Tags: java

I have a string containing this:

> `D:\ptc\Windchill_10.0\Windchill\wtCustom\wt\lifecycle\StateRB.rbInfo`.

I want to get just this part:

> `wt\lifecycle\StateRB`

How can I do that?

Comment: Those aren't the last three words, you dropped rbinfo. Clarify.

Comment: @ruakh I have used the below code:                              String[] str_array = path.split("wt"); ArrayList<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
list.add(str_array)                                               for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
System.out.println("*************"+list.get(i).toString());
        } I get the output as: *************[Ljava.lang.String;@addbf1

Comment: @Junuxx - Ya rbInfo has to be dropped

Comment: @gouthami: To edit your question, please go to http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18201696/edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply spilt whole path to parts and then get the parts you want.

```
String path = "D:\ptc\Windchill_10.0\Windchill\wtCustom\wt\lifecycle\StateRB.rbInfo";
String[] parts = path.split("\\");
parts = Arrays.copyOfRange(parts, parts.length-3, parts.length);
```

Or you can get throught string using loop (this seems to be better)

```
int index = 0, i = 0;
Stack<String> al = new Stack<String>();
while((index = path.lastIndexOf()))!=-1 && i < 3) {
    al.push((path = path.substring(index)));
    i++;
}
String[] parts = (String[])al.toArray(); //if you don't have array elements
                                         // in correct order, you can use 
                                         // Collections.reverse with Arrays.asList 
                                         // applied on array
```

Comment: (Nit Pick) What happens if there aren't 3 parts...:P

Comment: @user35443-I am getting this exception :                               Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unexpected internal error near index 1
\

Comment: Try "\\\\" or try to compile pattern using Pattern.compile("\\") and pass it as argument for split, or use my second solution, that should be, as @MadProgrammer pointed, better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use string tokeniezer with \ delimiter and fetch only last three string tokens. i hope that above path going to be constant always.

Comment: No the above path is not constant

Answer (score 0):

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

Check the above link

example :

```
  String Str = new String("Welcome to Tutorialspoint.com");
  System.out.print("Return Value :" );
  System.out.println(Str.substring(10) );

  System.out.print("Return Value :" );
  System.out.println(Str.substring(10, 15) );
```

Comment: My path is never a constant